# Convert value to compare in NSPredicate

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate, predicate

I am trying to use NSPredicate with Swift and RealmSwift. I want to filter a Realm collection, with one predicate being date related. The dates are stored as Strings in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` — how do I convert this to a Date so I can compare it to today, as part of the predicate?

My [non-working] attempt so far:

```swift
let today = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "nextReview <= %@", argumentArray: [today, dateFormatter]) {
    let nextReviewDate = dateFormatter.date(from: $0.nextReview)
    return nextReviewDate ?? today <= today
}

...

var cardsToReview: [RealmCard] = Cards.filter(compoundPredicate).map { $0 }
```

Comment: You need to call `let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: today)`, and then `let preduiate = NSPredicate(format: "nextReview = %@", dateString)`

Comment: That would only be true if the date is today, though (comparing strings). I need to convert `nextReview` to a Date, as I need to compare for dates <= today

Comment: What kind of init for NSPredicate is it that takes a closure? Is it something declared in realm and if so how is the closure parameter defined?

Comment: I'm not sure, really. Maybe it doesn't take a closure?

Comment: There's a great answer but it's often best to store dates as a date. Then the entire query becomes this `let results = realm.objects(RealmCard.self).where { $0.nextReview <= today }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things more complicated than needed. Since you have the date format "yyyy-MM-dd" in your database you can directly compare the strings since they will always have the same order as when converted to dates.

```
let today = dateFormatter.string(from: .now)
let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "nextReview <= %@", today)
```